# Windows Vista firewall blocks Java application

Tags: firewall, windows-vista, java

I'm currently working with vista on a domain account with VERY restricted permissions. Every time I'm using a new application which tries to reach the network, my boss has to input his admin password to open the firewall!

I wrote a Java app which needs internet access. I tried to debug it. Windows asked for the admin password. My boss was busy that time and a had to cancel the process.

If I run the application again, the firewall message does not come up again. I looked in the firewall settings at the exceptions list. I activated the exceptions for eclipse and for the jdk, but nothing changed.

How do I configure the firewall to let my application communicate or to ask me again after the admin password?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whoa. Your boss is a dictator. :o

Answer (score 2):

Do you have sufficient-enough access on your machine to access the advanced settings and control app for the Windows Firewall, `wf.msc`?

Go to your Start menu, and then in the Search box, type `wf.msc`, which should find the app in your Start menu.  Run it (and authorize it to run when UAC asks).  You should then get a "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" window, and on the left-hand side, you should see a few listed rulesets, including Outbound Rules.  If you click on that, I suspect you'll find a rule that's denying your applet access to the outbound network; delete it, and you should be back in business.